# Mongo DB: How to enable authentication only on single database

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-security

Assume, I have 3 databases AX,BX,CX

I want to enable authentication only on the DB CX.

My understanding is, we can enable authentication only on port (example-27017).

Can you pleas help me in setting up authentication only on CX DB

Comment: You cannot do that and it's all or nothing. If you want authentication on one source but not on the others, then you actually run separate instances. Not that it is recommended to run ANY instance without authentication enabled. You're also asking on the wrong site since Stack Overflow is for **programming** questions. You ask questions about database configuration on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com). It would be appreciated if you removed your question and if you want to discuss it further, then ask the question there instead.

Comment: Hello, the new versions of MongoDB require user and pass in any DB but you can add authentication if you follow the next article. https://medium.com/mongoaudit/how-to-enable-authentication-on-mongodb-b9e8a924efac

Comment: ok, thanks for the information